# Product name of configurable product not saving in store other than default

Tags: magento, store, configurable-product

This is a bug in Magento 1.4.2.0 (bug also present in 1.5.0.0-rc2). When trying to save a configurable product in a store view other than the default, the "Name" property is not properly saved. The product name for the default store automatically jumps back after saving the configurable product. All other configurable product properties are saved correctly.

This problem is discussed in:

- Magento's [forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/215467/)
- Magento's Bug Tracking [System](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=10800)

I have developed a few extensions for Magento, and tried to find and correct the bug, but unfortunately this issue is beyond my current Magento capabilities.

Any ideas?

Comment: Magento 1.5.0.0 final just came out, and the bug persists :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in Magento 1.5.1.0; for those who don't want to upgrade, a working solution is presented here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/215467/P30/.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try a setName() on $item during the add to cart event? (we are talking about an $item of the $quote obj)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I didn't try your solution, after my post several other solutions were present in the Magento foruns (links in my original question); I ended up not having time to try any of them, but meanwhile version Magento 1.5.1.0 came out, and this bug is resolved. Many thanks anyway!